# Statistical methods used for testing the homogeneity of the sample

Tags: spectroscopy

So, if I have multiple FTIR spectra each taken on different location of the sample and averaged from ~20 spectra, how can I check if the sample is homogeneous, i.e., if there are statistically significant differences between the spectra based on location? For visuals, I tried to compute at each wavenumber confidence upper and lower limits, but I am not sure if this method is valid even for visualisation and it does not give anything exact or quantitative.

Comment: It is a statistical problem, which can be solved with maybe 95% degree of confidence, using the chi-squared test.

Comment: Without seeing the spectra it is hard to advise , but presumably you have a set of peaks that you expect to find. If you have a 'standard spectrum' then use this to compare peaks of others  and so remove poor samples. Plotting this spectrum on x vs each of the rest on y and making a contour plot may help to do this pairwise. As the spectra are likely to be so different due to extraneous (unimportant) lines a conventional stats method may not work.

Comment: @Maurice Here I tried to construct chi squared test in R, but got a very large value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714065/chi-square-construction-in-r .

Comment: @ User. Well ! What can I say ? I don't know your numerical values. And even if I would have known them, I could not change the chi squared value...

Comment: @Maurice Ok, the problem was that I haven't divided everything by N.